# Solve $y''''-2y'''+2y'-y=e^x.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**My attempt:** The characteristic polynomial and the solutions gives the homogenous solutions $$p(r)=r^4-2r^3+2r-1=(r+1)(r-1)^3\Rightarrow y_h=Ae^{-x}+(B+Cx+Dx^2)e^{x}.$$

In order to find the particular solution, let's substitute $y=ze^x,$ where $z=z(x).$ We obtain a new differential equation in terms of $z(x)$, whose characteristic equation is

$$p(r-1)=(r-1)^4-2(r-1)^3+2(r-1)-1=r^4-6r^3+12r^2-8r.$$

This means that we get $z''''-6z'''+23z''-8z'=1,$ after dividing both sides with $e^x>0.$ So the particular solution in terms of $z$ is $z_p=-\frac{x}{8}$ and this gives $y_p=z_pe^x=-\frac{xe^x}{8}.$ Finally we have that

$$y(x)=y_h+y_p=Ae^{-x}+(B+Cx+Dx^2)e^x-\frac{xe^x}{8}.$$

Which is wrong, because the last term should be $+\frac{x^3e^x}{12}.$ **Need help sorting this out**, but other methods of solving are welcome.

Comment: Your particular solution _can't possibly be_ of the form $Cxe^{x}$ because that is already a solution to the homogeneous problem as you have it written. So I'm guessing you've made a mistake in your computation for $y_{h}$, or you have applied the variation of parameters method incorrectly. Is that actually how you use variation of parameters for a _fourth order_ ODE? Genuinely asking, as even going from first order to second order ODE the approach becomes more complicated. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

Comment: I don't think you factored the original characteristic polynomial correctly.

Comment: @rogerl: It is correct, I doublechecked with wolframalpha.

Comment: Well, the constant term on the left is $-1$, but if you expand $(r+1)(r-3)^3$ you get a constant term of $-27$.

Comment: $$p(r)=r^4-2r^3+2r-1=(r+1)(r-{\color{red} 1})^3\Rightarrow y_h=Ae^{-x}+(B+Cx+Dx^2)e^{{\color{red} x}}$$

Comment: @rogerl - Sorry roger, a blind man is blind. But that doesn't change the last term.

Comment: @Parseval the characteristic equation for $z$ should be $p(r+1) = r^3(r+2)$ instead of $p(r-1)$.

Comment: @Parseval see my answer in how to transform this sort of ODE, the $e^{-x}y$ there is your $z$.

Comment: I'll answer to your nice solution in a sec. I think this comment actually exactly what's wrong with my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be a shorthand for the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$. For any constant $a$ and function $f(x)$, we have the identity

$$e^{ax} D(e^{-ax}f(x)) = (D-a) f(x)$$

We will abuse notation and write this sort of relation as 
$$e^{ax} D e^{-ax} = D - a$$
The $e^{\pm ax}$ here should be interpreted as an operator on the space of function whose effect on any function is pointwise multiplication by $e^{\pm ax}$.

For any polynomial $P(t)$, we have following identity on operators.

$$e^{ax}P(D)e^{-ax} = P(D-a)$$

Notice $r^4 - 2r^3 + 2r - 1 = \color{red}{(r-1)^3(r+1)}$ instead of what stated in the original version of question. The ODE at hand can be rewritten as

$$(D-1)^3(D+1) y = e^x \iff \left[ e^x D^3(D+2) e^{-x} \right] y = e^x
\iff \left[ D^3(D+2) \right] (e^{-x}y) = 1
$$
It is easy to see $\frac12\frac{x^3}{3!} = \frac{x^3}{12}$ is a solution for
$D^3(D+2) f = 1$. As a consequence, the original equation has $\frac{x^3}{12} e^x$ as a particular solution.

Comment: This seems brilliant, I really want to learn to work with operators like this. So you have some explaining to do, sir. First of all, why is the identity $$e^{ax} D(e^{ax}f(x)) = (D-a) f(x)$$ true (Same question for)? I get that $$e^{ax} D(e^{ax}f(x)) = e^{2ax}(D+a) f(x)$$ when I differentiate.  I know that the operator $D$ has linear properties, but I don't see how the first two identeties follow.

Comment: @Parseval It is a typo, it should be $e^{ax}D(e^{-ax}f(x)) = (D-a)f(x)$. thanks for catching that.

Comment: But in your second line you have that $e^{ax}De^{-ax}=D-a,$ how come $f(x)$ just disapears like that? P.S. I've looked at your other answers here at stackexchange, you seem to possess some serious skills in math what do you do for a living? Any way to chatt/email you about math questions except here on stack? Thanks buddy!

Comment: @Parseval The first relation $e^{ax}D(e^{-ax}f(x)) = (D-a)f(x)$ is a relation among functions. It says that when you apply two different operators to same function $f(x)$, you get back the same result. Since this is true for any differentiable function $f(x)$, the two operator is considered to be equal to each other. This is what the second line $e^{ax} D e^{-ax} = D - a$ means (the $e^{\pm ax}$ on the second line refers to the operator of pointwise multiplication by corresponding function)

Answer (score 1):

made for the particular solution the ansatz $$y_P=Ae^xx^3+Be^xx^2+Ce^xx+De^x$$

Comment: just make it $Ax^3e^x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I think I'll wait for someone to spot my mistake. Important to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Observe that $$y_h=Ae^{−x}+(B+Cx+Dx^2)e^{{\color{red} 3x}}.$$